# How to implement the google login in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am pretty new to the angular world, now am stuck with a problem in implementing the google login.
I have created a button which on click will redirect me to google login page and from there after signing in the users will get redirected to the homepage. The main problem is that the login details are not stored in my firebase console. I don't know what is causing this error. So I'm sharing my code :

login.component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="login()" >Login with google</button>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';


@Component({
  selector: 'mt-login',
  templateUrl: './mt-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mt-login.component.css']
})
export class MtLoginComponent {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth ){}

  login() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).catch(err => {console.log(err)});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the onAuthStateChanged observable in order to receive the authenticate state change.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'mt-login',
  templateUrl: './mt-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mt-login.component.css']
})
export class MtLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
  }

  login() {
    return this.afAuth.auth
      .signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())     
      .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
  }
}
```